# SQL Server 2017 - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Tags: sql-server

I  exhausted 2 hours on google searching for answers, without any solutions. I need serious help with this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.MySqlTable
```

that's the only line of code on my page, when I execute it, I get

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Here's a screenshot:

[Drop Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDHs1.png)

I just don't get why I can't drop the table.

What's weird is that it does drop on my PC, on this school laptop, nothing.I installed SQL Server 2017 on both. VS 2013 on my PC for later, hopefully, and VS 2015 on my Laptop. But, I haven't integrated those yet.

Comment: Check the compatibility level of your database. Looks like your DB is in different compatibility level

Comment: If you just want to drop the table, remove the `IF EXISTS` from the statement, and run it. That is a newer feature in SQL Server, and it should work, but if you don't need it, get rid of it. No need to waste 2 hours on this.

Comment: 'Select @@Version' -- maybe you're not connected to the instance you think you are

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available only on SQL Server 2016 which is compatibility level of 130. Check your db on what compatibility level is.

```
select name, compatibility_level from sys.databases
```

If it is less than 130 you can alter it to 130 (2016) or 140 (2017) as below

```
 alter database testdb set compatibility_level = 130
```

Comment: The database compatibility level makes no difference with this feature. I just ran this against a database with 100 (2008) compatibility on a 2016 server without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously hate these things sometimes.

I removed **IF EXISTS** from my code, and simply did the usual **DROP TABLE** and it worked -_-

The first time I tried to drop a table on SQL Server 2017, it failed. After an hour on the internet, I learned that I had I had to use the IF EXISTS clause, and guess what, It worked.
When I got this laptop and installed the same SQL Server 2017, I obviously tried what took me an hour to find, **DROP TABLE IF EXISTS**, though that failed.

Thanks everyone.

Though, why did I use different DROP statements in the same version of SQL Server 2017?

I have a feeling I'm going to encounter more problems in the future.

Comment: The time it failed was because it wasn't created yet and you can't drop a table that doesn't exist. Then you tried an IF EXISTS clause in a manner that didn't work. There are other ways to do this though.  Use IF OBJECT_ID('database..tableName) IS NULL DROP TABLE tableName.

Comment: Did you run `SELECT @@VERSION`? What was the result?

Comment: @Martin Smith - This is the result **Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)   Feb 20 2014 20:04:26   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )**  . I expected to see 2017, maybe it's because I installed SQL Server 2014, before installing 2017, I didn't even uninstall the first one. On my PC, I only installed 2017 without a prior installation of 2014. I won't be home for a couple of days to check what version is on my PC

Comment: Well that's the answer then. You are connecting to a 2014 instance and that syntax is 2016+